# undefined local variable or method `json' in JBuilder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, jbuilder

When I try get all categories (index action) there is an error:

```
undefined local variable or method `json'
```

But in show action everything fine. All files has .jbuilder extension.
Here is controller code:

```
def index
  @categories = Category.all
end

# GET /categories/1
# GET /categories/1.json
def show
  @category = Category.find(params[:id])
end
```

Stack trace:

> app/views/categories/index.json.builder:1:in`_app_views_categories_index_json_builder___502133872307116590_70140532925300'
>   actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_view/template.rb:145:in`block in render'
>   activesupport (3.2.11) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:125:in `instrument'
>
>   actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_view/template.rb:143:in`render'

Comment: The stack trace and your index.json.jbuilder might be helpful

Comment: index.json.jbuilder is empty.

Answer (score 121, accepted):

Try to rename your file `index.json.builder` to `index.json.jbuilder`

Comment: I also had to restart my server.

Comment: I did this and restarted my server, and still have issues.

Comment: Where is this file? Can't find it anywhere. How can I get another one if I can't find the original?

Comment: I also am blind and potentially dumb.

Comment: changing `.builder` to `.jbuilder` works. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You could also rename it to `index.json.jpbuilder` and use this gem: https://github.com/bigjason/jpbuilder (if you want JSONP)